# Partial edits in the review queues

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

What is the approach of the reviewing queues? Is partial editing allowed? I.e. I can improve code formatting, but leave grammatical and spelling errors untouched. Or even the other way around.

Or should I try to improve everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should aim to correct *all* errors in the post, to the best of your ability. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting **all** problems that you observe.

You've got to do something to deserve those +2 reputation points when your edit is approved...

The main reason for this is that your edits need to be *reviewed* (because you have less than [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)), which takes up valuable time from other users. If you don't do this, your edits *might* be rejected, because they are not improving the post enough. Too many rejected edits will get you banned from editing posts for a while.

Comment: The key phrase is "to the best of your ability". I've seen a few editors whose edits _introduced_ grammatical errors in a post. They meant well, but they overestimated their command of the English language.

Answer (score 2):

You should always strive to correct all errors of a post for editing.

Since editing bumps a question back onto the front page, we don't need partial edits. Leaving obvious problems with the post untouched is grounds to have a suggested edit rejected, and people in the review queue will often do so.

Since you have <2000 reputation, your edits go through the Suggested Edits review queue before being applied.