# Partial Edits and Review Queue Workload

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In thinking about [Partial edits in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327468/partial-edits-in-the-review-queues) for First Posts or Late Answers where a post can be improved for ["spit and polish"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/2827397) issues like:

- code formatting
- placing images in line
- grammar and typos
- etc...

I will propose those edits when I see them. However, since I have a rep level that requires those edits to be approved, I have by definition created workload for someone else to have to review and approve those edits. I fear that this might be causing wasted effort because a later reviewer might find that the original post should be removed and, therefore, the edits may become unnecessary. I don't propose formatting edits to posts that are clearly spam or abusive (for example), but there are circumstances where proposed edits may still be helpful as an interim review for posts that others may later flag.

If my "spit and polish" changes make it easier for a later reviewer to more quickly determine the quality of a question or answer then this seems like useful effort. However, if a later reviewer feels the original post should have been flagged, my spit and polish effort is wasted at best (which I would not be concerned with) or result in increased (and potentially unnecessary) effort for others at worst -- which I of course want to avoid.

Should reviewers propose spit and polish (only) edits for content where:

- they have used up their daily flag limit?
- they would otherwise skip a post?
- others might feel that the post doesn't "deserve" the re-work?

Comment: If you feel the post should be flagged as unclear/not answerable you are, by definition, saying that even if you *were* to edit it it would still be unable to be answered; in my opinion proposing an edit to it is therefore a fruitless endeavour when the question could well be closed. Suggest the edit if you truly think it'll improve the question, and the question is on topic. There's little point polishing a turd; it's still a turd.

Comment: Which action do you pick after your edit? If you press "No action needed" or "I'm done" the post will no longer be in the review queue, so noone else will check if it is even on-topic.

Comment: @BDL After making an edit to a post, `I'm Done` becomes selected automatically. I then `Submit`.

Comment: @Larnu I hear you. However, if it's a post that a reviewer would otherwise `Skip` (i.e., not clearly bad), should they not make the edits? Presumably the edits would improve the post and help the a later reviewer take action. Agree for instances where a reviewer has no flags left and would otherwise want to flag it.

Comment: I was specifically talking about when you feel you should be flagging the question, @DaveL17 , not skipping as you don't know if it's on topic or not.

Comment: @DaveL17 when you click I'm done, you tell the system you did everything that was required and that there is no need for anyone else to check the question. Thus "fixing it for other reviewers" doesn't work because there are no other reviewers after you. If you didn't fix anything to make the question on topic, please at least skip after the edit.

Comment: @BDL thanks for clarifying for me that selecting skip doesn't negate the proposed edit.

Comment: Shouldn't it be clearly written in the review queue that clicking "I'm done" will make the question leave the queue and it will not be reviewed by anyone else ?